# Gatling: is it possible to display Group information rather than Global in the console?

Tags: gatling

Once the simulation is finished, the Global Information table is displayed:

[image]

Is it possible to have it display the Group information instead?
This is my code:

```
  val addMeterLatency2 = scenario(s"Add a meter, submit readings, get average consumption")
    .exec(_.set(responseStatus, 0))
    .group("AddLatency"){
      exec(
        http("Add a meter")
          .post(":9002/meters")
          .headers(headers)
          .body(
            StringBody(
            s"""{
                           "location" : {
                                         "latitude" : $latitude,
                                         "longitude" : $longitude
                                        },
                           "metadata" : {
                                         "description" : "$meter",
                                         "houseId" : "$houseId"
                                        }
                    }""")
        ).asJSON
        .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs(responseId))
    )

    .asLongAs(session => session.attributes(responseStatus).asInstanceOf[Int] != 200) {
      exec(
        http("Check if meter has been added to DB")
          .get(":9002/meters/${responseId}")
          .headers(headers)
          .check(status.saveAs(responseStatus))
      )
    }
```

I would like the final table of results, **in the console**, to display results for the ***AddLatency*** group rather than Global.

**EDIT**

The reason I want this is this:

I have an assertion put on the AddLatency group, like this:

```
  setUp(addMeterLatency2.inject(atOnceUsers(4)))
    .assertions(
      details("AddLatency")
        .responseTime
        .mean.lte(1000)
    )
    .protocols(httpConf)
```

When the simulation is finished, the assertion is looking at the mean response time for the AddLatency group - correctly! - but the mean response time value for the group is not displayed in the console; you have to open the html report to see it. So just looking at the results in the console it's not instantly apparent whether the assertion did its job.

Comment: Where are you, Stephane?